# SignalR not working with AFNetworking2.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr

I'm included `SignalR` classes via pods as pod 'SignalR-ObjC' in my objective C project.
I'm getting error `"AFHttpClient.h"` file not found because of updated AFNetworking(currently >2.x) classes.
I don't want to degrade `AFNetworking` version to 1.3 or earlier Kindly let me know if there is any alternative of implementing SignalR in `iOS`.

Thanks
-Sandeep

Comment: I thing your signalR is not a problem check your AFnetworking